# It is possible to use JavaFX in Groovy using the same syntax as in Java?

Tags: groovy, javafx

I am using jdk1.8.0_25.

I am trying to run a JavaFX app file below which, when named 'HelloWorldMain.java', compiles and runs OK with javac/java. I renamed it as 'HelloWorldMain.groovy' and can't run it using Groovy.

Is there a simple way to run this file using Groovy with no or minimal modification, preferably without additional software like GroovyFX? And if I have to use GroovyFX, can I run this pure Java code without modification?

```
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.event.ActionEvent; 
import javafx.event.EventHandler; 
import javafx.scene.Group; 
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.control.Button; 
import javafx.stage.Stage; 

/** 
* 
* @author cdea 
*/ 
public class HelloWorldMain extends Application {

/** 
* @param args the command line arguments 
*/ 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Application.launch(args); 
} 

@Override 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World"); 
    Group root = new Group(); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250); 
    Button btn = new Button(); 
    btn.setLayoutX(100); 
    btn.setLayoutY(80); 
    btn.setText("Hello World"); 
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) { 
            System.out.println("Hello World"); 
        }
    }); 
    root.getChildren().add(btn); 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.show(); 
}

}
```

I am trying to run it as

> groovy HelloWorldMain.groovy

and getting the following output in command line:

```
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:             javafx.application.Application$launch
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     javafx.application.Application$launch
        at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:260)
        at javafx.application.Application$launch.call(Unknown Source)
        at HelloWorldMain.main(HelloWorldMain.groovy:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application$launch
        at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:248)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace the main method with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(HelloWorldMain, args);
}
```

The error basically gives you the answer: no you can not just copy the files **in all cases**.  There are differences between groovy and java (e.g. http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html).  Groovy comes with a tool called `java2groovy` that **might** help migrate.

But as groovy runs fine with java code, why bother?  Migrate the parts, that are better off using groovy and keep the java parts around for now.